# Angular jsonp is not workin

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-http

I'm trying to making `jsonp` call using below code but doesn't seems to be working for me.

**Code**

```
var url = 'http://z:15957/Category/Categories?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
$http.jsonp(url).success(function (data) {
    $scope.results = data.feed.entry;
});
```

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: i think this url is wrong

Comment: @NitishKumar right, get error but this is a point of callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue appears to be with your CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) issue. Your `.success` callback will not fire after making this call, but `.error` will. See the working example with the valid `URL` and see the `.success` callback executed successfully.

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/20fkapwo/)

```
var url = 'http://z:15957/Category/Categories?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

// valid URL example
//url = 'http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/wtmpeachtest.wordpress.com/posts?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'

$http.jsonp(url)               
     .success(function (data) {
         console.log(data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
         console.log('error');         
    });
```